# How to prevent page updates after load with Python Selenium Webdriver (Firefox)

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm using Python Selenium to save data into a spreadsheet from a webpage using Firefox, but the page continually updates data causing errors relating to stale elements. How do I resolve this?

I've tried to turn off JavaScript but that's doesn't seem to do anything. Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Check the networks tab to see how it updates

Comment: Do you understand what causes stale element exceptions? Don't get an element until you need to use it. Don't expect that any element reference will be good for any period of time. It's hard to recommend anything when you haven't shown any code at all, provided a link to the page, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the data at the page in the specific moment of time you can

1. [get the current page HTML source](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.page_source) using `WebDriver.page_source` function
2. write it into a file
3. open the file from the disk using [WebDriver.get()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.get) function
4. that's it, you should be able to work with the local copy of the page which will never change

Example code:

```
driver.get("http://seleniumhq.org")
with open("mypage.html", "w") as mypage:
    mypage.write(driver.page_source)
    mypage.close()
    driver.get(os.getcwd() + "/" +  (mypage.name))
    #do what you need with the page source
```

another approach is using [WebDriver.find_element](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element) function wherever you need to interact with the element.

so instead of

```
myelement = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//your_selector")
# some other action
myelement.getAttribute("interestingAttribute")
```

perform **find** any time you need to interact with the element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//your_selector").getAttribute("interestingAttribute")
```

or even better go for [Explicit Wait](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) of the element you need:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//your/selector"))).get_attribute("href")
```

Comment: This looks perfect, will give it a try!